# Define function in environment that changes an object in the environment

Tags: r

I would like to write a function that returns an environment containing a function which assigns the value of an object inside the environment. For example, what I want to do is:

```
makeenv <- function() {
  e <- new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv)
  e$x <- 0
  e$setx <- function(k) { e$x <- k }  # NOT OK
  e
}
```

I would like to fix the `e$setx` function above. The behavior of the above is weird to me:

```
e1 <- makeenv()
e1$x
## [1] 0
e1$setx
## function(k) e$x <- k
## <environment: 0x7f96144d8240>
e1$setx(3)     # Strangely, this works.
e1$x
## [1] 3
# --------- clone ------------
e2 <- new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv)
e2$x <- e1$x
e2$setx <- e1$setx
e2$x
## [1] 3
# ----- e2$setx() changes e1$x -----
e2$setx(7)   # HERE
e2$x         # e2$x is not changed.
## [1] 3
e1$x         # e1$x is changed instead.
## [1] 7
```

Could someone please help me understand what is going on here? I especially don't understand why `e2$setx(7)` sets `e1$x` to 7 rather than issuing an error. I think I am doing something very wrong here.

I would also like to write a correct function `e$setx` inside the `makeenv` function that correctly assigns a value to the `x` object in the environment `e`. Would it be possible to have one without using S4 or R6 classes? I know that a function like `setx <- function(e,k) { e$x <- k }` works, but to me `e1$setx(5)` looks more intuitive than `setx(e1,5)` and I would like to investigate this possibility first. Is it possible to have something like `e$setx <- function(k) { self$x <- k }`, say, where `self` refers to the `e` preceding the `$`?

This page [The equivalent of 'this' or 'self' in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447966/the-equivalent-of-this-or-self-in-r) looks relevant, but I like to have the effect without using S4 or R6. Or am I trying to do something impossible? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `local` to evaluate the function definition in the environment:

```
local(etx <- function (k) e$x <- k, envir = e)
```

Alternatively, you can also change the function’s environment *after the fact*:

```
e$setx <- function(k) e$x <- k
environment(e$setx) <- e
```

… but neither is strictly necessary in your case, since you probably don’t need to create a brand new environment. Instead, you can reuse the current calling environment. Doing this is a very common pattern:

```
makeenv <- function() {
  e <- environment()
  x <- 0
  setx <- function(k) e$x <- k
  e
}
```

Instead of `e$x <- k` you could also write `e <<- k`; that way, you don’t need the `e` variable at all:

```
makeenv <- function() {
  x <- 0
  setx <- function(k) x <<- k
  environment()
}
```

… however, *I actually recommend against this*: `<<-` is error-prone because it looks for assignment targets in all parent environments; and if it can’t find any, it creates a new variable in the global environment. It’s better to explicitly specify the assignment target.

---

However, note that none of the above changes the observed semantics of your code: when you copy the function into a new environment, it retains its old environment! If you want to “move over” the function, you explicitly need to reassign its environment:

```
e2$setx <- e1$setx
environment(e2$setx) <- e2
```

… of course writing that entire code manually is pretty error-prone. If you want to create value semantics (“deep copy” semantics) for an environment in R, you should wrap this functionality into a function:

```
copyenv <- function (e) {
  new_env <- list2env(as.list(e, all.names = TRUE), parent = parent.env(e), hash = TRUE)
  new_env$e <- new_env
  environment(new_env$setx) <- new_env
  new_env
}
```

```
e2 <- copyenv(e1)
```

Note that the `copyenv` function is *not* trying to be general; it needs to be adapted for other environment structures. There is no good, general way of writing a deep-copy function for environments that handles all cases, since a general function can’t know how to handle self-references (i.e. the `e` in the above): in your case, you want to preserve self-references (i.e. change them to point to the new environment). But in other cases, the reference might need to point to something else.

This is a *general problem* of deep copying. That’s why the R `serialize` function, for instance, has `refHook` parameter that tells the function how to serialise environment references.

Comment: Thank a lot! The `copyenv` function works for the `makeenv` using `<<-`. It is also possible to make it work for the `makeenv` beginning with `e <- environment()`?

Comment: @chan1142 Oh right, I had forgotten that. Yes, it’s possible but it’s unfortunately a bit messy. See update.

Comment: Thanks! I see `new_env$e <- new_env`. Fascinating! Also thanks for the detailed explanation. Very helpful.